# Button elements on separate lines in html source displayed differently if on same line of html

Tags: css, html, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone explain why the presence of whitespace/newlines between button elements in the html source renders different output using Bootstrap 3?  The first row of elements have the required gap (margin?) I was expecting but if I put the same three button elements on the same line then they are squashed with no separation.  Please refer to the jsfiddle which includes the latest CDN for bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Mini button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Mini button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Mini button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Mini button</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Mini button</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Mini button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Different spacing depending on html source code whitespace]

https://jsfiddle.net/stevegrove/zk2mbeax/1/

Please note: I am not after three buttons on three lines in the rendered web page - I would like them horizontally drawn be that inline or inline-block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whitespace in between inline elements (line break or space in your source code) will be condensed to a single space per the html spec.  whitespace between block level elements will be ignored.  You could make them `display:block` and `float:left;`

https://jsfiddle.net/712ykgso/1/ for an example

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ for much more thorough breakdown.

Comment: The problem arose because I am adding buttons using JS, and some of my page uses "fixed" html where I add new lines in the html source for clarity, but the buttons added by JS are usually added to the DOM on the same line so I get two different layouts.  Looks like I need to find a solution that that will cope with this that removes the "whitespace between inline block elements" problem you linked to.